# IIS keeps using wrong default document

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using IIS version 10 on windows 10 64bit. I created a website and pointed it to the right file location.  I set the default document to EventDetails.html.  I did this in IIS - Default Documents, the properties page in VS2015, and in web.config.  But when I right click on the site to browse, it keeps looking for index.html.  I don't have one nor do I have it in any code.  I did a global search.  Why does it keep looking for index.html and how can I get it to go to my page?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried restarting IIS services in case there is a glitch or cached issue going on?

Comment: Paste screen shots, especially explain what is "when I right click on the site to browse". If that's an action in Solution Explorer of Visual Studio, I am not surprised that it does not work.

Comment: I've tried restarting IIS, the site itself, and the whole computer.  I right click in IIS on teh site node, click Manage Website -> Browse.  Just to add, In IIS, default document is enabled and so is directory browsing.  I've even checked the IISExpress config files even though that should have nothingt to do with it.  I am just clueless on why it is even looking for index.html in the first place.  Any help is appreciated.